# How can i upload video to Twitter using IOS

Tags: ios, swift, post

I have a local video link, and i want when the user press the button -> show twitter app with my video and title there (without using UIActivityViewController), just by pressing the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to choose which way you want to go to upload a video, i.e. post a tweet with just that title you've mentioned.

**Option 1**
Use the [HTTP API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet) and create a URLRequest that contains the video as 'attachment'. You have to handle authentication first or the request will most likely fail.

**Option 2** (Not really an option anymore)
Another way would be the iOS SDK provided, as given in the other example here. Problem is: there is [no longer an official Twitter SDK](https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2018/discontinuing-support-for-twitter-kit-sdk.html) for iOS. You could try your luck with the [archived OpenSource SDK](https://github.com/twitter-archive/twitter-kit-ios) but maintainability is pretty decent with this.